# Iterate over a map to print out meaningful textual representations of its contents

Tags: java, iterator

I need to iterate over a map which contains Strings for keys and objects for values.  I would like to iterate over this map to print it contents, which would include the state of the variables in the objects.  I have tried this so far:

```
/**
  * Iterates over the map to print out textual
  * representations of its contents.
  */

public String printMap() {
    String list = "This is a list of members  ";
    for (String eachMember : memberNumbers.keySet()) {
        list = list + memberNumbers.get(eachMember);
    }      
    return list;
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with this?  What is breaking for you?

Comment: You're trying to put the value object into a `String`, which calls the `toString` method of the object. If it isn't set correctly, you may get "garbage".

Comment: Note that it's better to iterate directly over the `entrySet` to avoid computing the hash for each `get`.

Answer (score 0):

whatever the value type of memberNumbers is, add a function called toString() (if its a custom object)

```
public String toString() {
    return this.name;
}
```

where this.name is a property in whatever object your putting inside memberNumbers